# Same IP address for multiple Bluemix Docker containers

Tags: networking, docker, ip, ibm-cloud

Like the title says, is it possible to run multiple Bluemix containers with the same public IP address, but with different ports exposed? (There should be no need to buy additional or waste IPv4 space.)

I'd like to run 6 differently parameterized (with environment variables) containers. The difference would be the exposed port numbers (and the inner application logic).

The only thing I need is to be able to access that port either with Docker configuration or other solutions, like NAT between these 6 images and a "router".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with IBM Containers.